# HTML5 connect DSLR as webcam

Tags: html, html5-video

Recently i've created an application in html5 to connect to a webcam and take photos. Is there any possibility to use dslr/slr as webcam so that it can be connected using html5? 
  I'm employed in a work of converting an application that uses activex to html5. It uses a canon dslr as a camera. but when i run the html5 application using that camera i get error. 
This is the code so far

```
if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
}
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({
        video: true
    }, connect, function(e) {
        alert('Error connecting to camera.');
    });
} else alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');
```

Comment: What error are you getting? From an app point of view a webcam is a webcam, if the operating system registers the camera as a webcam and makes it available to the browser then it will work. Sounds like your problem is not related to the app you're writing but without more information we cant say for sure

Comment: `if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                  navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia){
    navigator.getUserMedia({video:true}, connect, function(e) {
    alert('Error connecting to camera.');
    });
} else alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');`

This is my code to access webcam , i'm getting error connecting to camera error. but it's working when i run the activex appn.

Comment: I guess the pbm is not with the html5 but i'd like to know is there any way to achieve this

Comment: If your question is "can I capture video/images in a web application using a DSLR camera?" then yes, you can. The configuration steps in this tutorial may be relevant http://sparkosoft.com/how-to-use-dslr-as-webcam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use dslr as webcam , you will need the libraries of both open cv and aforge.net plus dslr's own sdk.
Aforge and Ozeki SDK together provide good libraries for accessing camera's, try them.